# assign variable from print function in PHP

Tags: php, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to capture PHP echo output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917057/possible-to-capture-php-echo-output)

Now I have:

```
function showwish()
{
  echo 'happy new year';
}
```

and I want to assign `$somevariable = showwish;`

How to do this task without any error.

Note: Not allow edit showwish function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showwish()
{
  ob_start();
  echo 'happy new year';
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Or if all your doing is returning one string:

```
function showwish()
{
  return 'happy new year';
}
```

---

Based on [comment below by the OP that he cannot edit the showwish fn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057219/assign-variable-from-print-function-in-php/14057247#comment19426813_14057247):

```
ob_start();
showwish();
$someVar = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Seems like it might make more sense for the buffering to be outside of the function.  If it were inside of the function, you might as well just use string concatenation. (Unless the end goal is to include a file as part of a basic templating function or something -- then it makes sense.)

Comment: Note: Not allow edit showwish function

Answer (score 4):

you should have

```
function showwish(){
    return 'happy new year';
}
```

and then either

```
echo showwish();
```

or

```
$fish = showwish();
```

or ask more practical question

Comment: Please, no edit showwish function. only edit $somevariable=?

Answer (score 2):

```
function showwish() {
    return 'happy new year';
}

$somevariable = showwish();

echo $somevariable;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use variable as like constant

```
define('showwish', 'something');
function showwish() {
    echo 'happy new year';
}
$somevariable = showwish;
echo $somevariable;
```