# How to use output buffering inside PHPUnit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit to test a function which downloads a file. I want to test that the correct file is downloaded and so my idea was to check the output of the function. I'm trying to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
$viewer->downloadById($fileId);
$output = ob_get_flush();
$this->assertEquals($expectedFileContents,$output);
```

The test passes/fails when it should, which is good. My issue is that the contents of the output buffer is also printed to the console. How do I hide this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) instead of `ob_get_flush()`. The former will remove the buffer without printing it and return its contents. The latter will do the same *and print* the contents of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks! I had *just* worked that one out for myself, and was coming back here to post the answer!

Comment: @user1578653, are downloading the file from an external website, executing HTTP request? (absolutely irrelevant to the issue in your question, just out of curiosity)

Comment: nope, in $viewer->downloadById() I am retrieving a BLOB from an Oracle database (which could be remote) and printing out the contents (after sending headers).